# how to set up yup validation based on value of CheckBox component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, yup

I have validationSchema

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    first_name: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
    last_name: Yup.string().required("Last name is required"),
    email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email("Email is invalid"),
    phone: Yup.string().required("Phone is required"),
    checkbox: Yup.bool().oneOf([true], 'You need to accept the terms and conditions'),
  });
```

I want to setup validation for component, based on checked value. Is it possible?

```
    return (
<form>
        <Checkbox
          name="checkbox"
          id="checkbox"
          label="I accept the terms and conditions"
          value={checked}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <div className={errors.checkbox ? 'form__error' : ''}>
              {errors.checkbox}
            </div>
        </div>
</form
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `validationFunction` and pass it as a parameter to `validate` property of `Checkbox`

```
const validationFunction = (value) => {
      if (!value) {
        return "You need to accept the terms and conditions";
      }
      return null;
    };


  return (
    <form>
      <Checkbox
        ...
        validate={validationFunction}
      />
      <div className={errors.checkbox ? 'form__error' : ''}>
        {errors.checkbox}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
```

Comment: @ann did it answered your question?